# Why does Apple use both private vars and properties with the same name in the Recipes code example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, private-members

I notice that Apple has what seems to be duplicate variable names:
2 properties and two ivars. Why does Apple do this?

```
//.h file
@interface TypeSelectionViewController : UITableViewController {
    @private
        Recipe *recipe;
        NSArray *recipeTypes;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSArray *recipeTypes;
```

And they then update the recipe instance below. Why have two variable with the same name?
Will one affect the recipe variable of the `parentViewController` since that recipe variable was set when presenting this view controller the code was in from the `parentViewController`?

```
//.m file
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If there was a previous selection, unset the accessory view for its cell.
    NSManagedObject *currentType = recipe.type;

    if (currentType != nil) {
        NSInteger index = [recipeTypes indexOfObject:currentType];
        NSIndexPath *selectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectionIndexPath];
        checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];    

     // Update the type of the recipe instance
    recipe.type = [recipeTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Deselect the row.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

This code is from Apple's [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) core data example:

First have a look at the `RecipeViewController's` didSelect delegate method, which will present the `TypeSelectionViewController` (child) view controller. Then have a look at that viewcontroller's `didSelect` delegate method where you will find the code implementation.

The reason I started looking at this is because I was interested how the parent's tableView cell got updated based on the selection in the `ChildViewController` in editing mode.

To see this for yourself, do the following:

1. Run the application
2. Select the `Recipes` tab
3. Click on a recipe - Chocolate Cake.
4. Click the edit button on the top right
5. Make note of the current category - should be on desert - then click on it.
6. Then you will be taken to the child view controller
7. Click on a different category, then click back and you will notice that the category button for that recipe has magically been updated. And I don't know how that's happening.

Does it have something to do with the private ivars and properties? which affects the `parentViewController`'s cell?

My question i Guess is, how does selecting a category type in the child view controller's table affect the cell.text in the Parent View Controller's table? I can't see where the managedObjectcontext is saved in the child view controller for it to automatically update the parent View controller's cell text.

Comment: Where is this sample code from?  Can I see the full implementation?

Comment: Yes please check the updated post where I have posted a link

Comment: At the top of the .m there should be a line that says `@synthesize recipe = recipe;  @syntehsize recipeTypes = recipeTypes;`  It's just older code before they changed it to do most of that work for you in the background.

Comment: @Putz1103 please have a look at my updated question in `update 1`.

Comment: That code is all over the place, I have no answers for you.  They create the recipeTypes array property twice.  They lost me.

Comment: That code is over 3.5 years old. That may not sound like much, but the iphone has only been around 6.5, and the public API 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing here is relatively old code, and there's not much need to do this anymore, thanks to Objective-C auto-synthesis.

Nowadays, when you issue a `@property (nonatomic) NSArray *foo;`, you *implicitly* get a `@synthesize foo = _foo;` in your implementation file and an instance variable declaration in your header. You don't see this, the compiler "inserts" it automatically. `foo` is the `property` and `_foo` is the instance variable. (In your above example, the `@property` and backing instance variable are both the same name, which could get confusing very quickly. With the `foo` property,  you couldn't accidentally say `self._foo`, that doesn't exist. There's `self.foo` and `_foo`. With your example `recipe` is the ivar and `self.recipe` is the property. Very easy for one to quickly confuse the two when reading code.

Before the auto-synthesis, there was an intermediate step where you still needed a `@synthesize`, but you the backing instance variable was generated for you. These new features help you remove boilerplate code.

**Answering Update 1**

The code doing what you're wondering is in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. There's nothing magical here.  When you selected a new Category via the `TypeSelectionViewController`, the `NSManagedObject` is updated. Back in the `RecipeDetailViewController`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` pulls the lasted information from CoreData. `text = [recipe.type valueForKey:@"name"];`

You might be getting confused about what an `@property` really is. It's just syntactic sugar. A `@property` these days automatically creates accessor and mutator methods and a backing ivar. Properties themselves aren't areas to store data, it's just a quick way of generating some methods and backing ivars.

Example

```
@interface MyClass
{
        NSUInteger _foo;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (NSUInteger)foo
{
        return (_foo)
}

- (void)setFoo:(NSUInteger)newFoo
{
        _foo = newFoo;
}

@end
```

is equivalent to:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger foo;
@end
```

You save a lot of typing. When you get into things like `NSString` properties and different property modifiers like `strong` or `copy`, the amount of code you save (and memory management mistakes you avoid) in the mutators becomes much greater.

Comment: Updated. You should open a separate question with a new title if you need more help so others can chime in.

Comment: Hey greg, thats correct although I didnt want to waste space especially if the question was so related. My question was that assigning     `recipe.type = [recipeTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`somehow updated the Parent view controller's cell.text to row the user selected in the childViewcontroller. I cant see anywhere in that second block of code where something is saved? :S

Comment: In this case, that works because it's an `NSManagedObject`. That line is updating the object in the backing CoreData data store. The other view is always pulling out the most recent data about that object. If it were a plain old ObjC object, that wouldn't work, they would be different instances.

Comment: Ok thats great dude, so its just old code that hasn't been updated. So I can just get rid of the private variabels and it wouldnt make a difference. Could you please have a look at update 1? It's the main reason why i noticed the variables in the first place. When you look at the second code block, how does the parentViewController's cell text get updated? It must be something to do with core data

Comment: @Pavan my answer was updated after you posted, see *Answering Update 1*.

Comment: hey greg. you got my attention soon as you said that `NSManagedObject` was being updated in the `typeSelectionViewController`. How is this happening? I cant see any method that saves the managed object? Where is the link between the parent vc and the child vc.

Comment: So in the parentVC - `RecipeDetailViewController` - before pushing the childVC - `TypeSelectionViewController` - the `recipe` property in the childVC is being set from the parentVC's `recipe` property like so `((TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController).recipe = recipe;`. Then in the `TypeSelectionViewController` when something is selected, a new `NSManagedObject` variable is created which is then set with the `recipe` property. So are you saying, changing this new `NSManagedObject` propagates changes to the ParentVC's `recipe` property, since it was originally passed down from there?

Answer (score 0):

Your .h file should be your `public` api. You can re-declare your properties in your .m, implementation file, which are also considered `private`. For example

.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
@property (readonly) NSString *name;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyViewController
@property (readwrite) NSString *name
@end
```

Here we are declaring a public name property that is `readonly` and in your implementation you 're re-declaring the property so that you can use the setter accessor.

Comment: Properties are redeclared in class extention, not the implementation.